Como puedo hacer que un navbar cambie de color al llegar a una seccion
Estoy haciendo una aplicacion donde al bajar el navbar y llegar a la segunda seccion del documento, esta cambie a otro color, como puedo realizarlo con HTML, CSS y JavaScript?, aqui mi codigo;
<header id="header">
  <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <a href="#home"><h1>Adrian Gomez</h1></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="home">
  <h2 class="title">Welcome to our website</h2>
</section>
<section id="blog">
  <h2 class="lorem">Blog</h2>
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit suscipit
    velit delectus dicta aperiam perferendis recusandae modi ut quibusdam
    obcaecati cumque, hic doloremque officiis libero quaerat neque
    praesentium vitae. Neque?
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore
    eveniet sequi, architecto earum veniam autem deleniti exercitationem
    iure qui labore rerum consequatur delectus voluptatem. Minima
    praesentium accusantium at illum aut.
  </p>
</section>

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?, vi que usando el evento scroll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Se me ocurre una solucion sencillita para tu problema. Podriamos definir dos nombres para la clase del navbar, el cual cuando nos interese que este de un color "por defecto" se mantenga con el nombre de la clase original y cuando queramos que cambie de color le cambiemos el nombre a la clase.
No se si me he explicado bien... te lo muestro con codigo:
tu codigo html tal como esta

Para el codigo CSS:
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}


.navbar.active {
  background-color: #ff6347; 
}

section {
  height: 100vh; /* Para que cada sección llene la pantalla */
  padding: 20px;
}

Bueno aqui estoy definiendo los dos colores del navbar. (He escogido un color cualquiera, puede cambiarlo en background-color). Aparte he incluido una pequena transicion para que el cambio de color no sea brusco.
Algo que supongo que habras hecho es poner el tamano de la section que ocupe toda la pantalla, lo cual para el ejemplo nos viene mejor.
En cuanto a JavaScript:
// Cojo las clases basandome en los id para poder trabajar con ellas.
const navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');
const blogSection = document.getElementById('blog');

// Con esta funcion sabremos que hemos llegado a la funcion blog
function changeNavbarColorOnScroll() {
  const blogSectionTop = blogSection.getBoundingClientRect().top; // Con esto trabajamos con la posicion de la section blog. 
  
  // Comprobamos que la parte superior de la section blog esta en pantalla.
  if (blogSectionTop <= 0) {
    navbar.classList.add('active'); // Le cambiamos el nombre a la clase para usar el .navbar.active que habiamos modificado.
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('active'); // Si no estamos ahi, quitamos el active para volver al color original.
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', changeNavbarColorOnScroll); //Nos ponemos a la escucha con el 'scroll' que comentabas al final.

Lo único un poco rarillo aquí es getBoundingClientRect().top. Esto nos devuelve un objeto con información sobre la posición y el tamaño del elemento dentro de la ventana del navegador.
Si el valor devuelto es positivo significa que no hemos llegado a esa section. Si el valor es menor o igual que cero significa que ya hemos llegado a esa section o la hemos pasado.
Espero haberte ayudado, he intentado ser lo mas claro posible.
Cualquier cosa no dudes en comentarla para intentar ayudarte!
PD: En caso de que quieres cambiar el color del nav en cada section podrías probar con usar variables dentro de la función.
